# Highchart error with date values on xaxis

Tags: php, highcharts

I am trying to build a line chart but my highchart isn't rendering with the following code.
Could someone check what am I doing wrong?

```
$('#employee_chart').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'REPORTS AT A GLANCE (LAST 30 DAYS)'
        },
        xAxis: {            
            type: "datetime",
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: '%d'   
            },
            tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            min: Date.UTC(<?php echo date("Y, m, d",strtotime("-30 days"));?>),
            max: Date.UTC(<?php echo date("Y, m, d");?>)
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Unique Logins',
            data: [7, 6, 9, 14, 18, 21, 25, 26, 23, 18, 13, 9, 7, 6, 9, 14, 18, 21, 25, 26, 23, 18, 13, 9, 7, 6, 9, 14, 18, 21]
        }]
    });
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the error/problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing pointStart  which is cause of the issue.

```
  pointStart :someDate
```

See [Fiddle with similar issue](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/tYESu/213/) when no pointStart

and [Working fiddle when defined pointStart](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/tYESu/214/)

Comment: I didn't know this could be done like this. Pretty good
Got it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/e4fru078/1/

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be coming from your xaxis settings:
As you can see here your chart renders without these settings: http://jsfiddle.net/e4fru078/

```
            tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            min: Date.UTC(<?php echo date("Y, m, d",strtotime("-30 days"));?>),
            max: Date.UTC(<?php echo date("Y, m, d");?>)
```

I would recommend to look into [categories for your xaxis](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.categories):
example here: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/reflow-true/